# Is it natural and correct to say "correct something to something"?

Tags: word-usage

Could you tell if it is natural and correct to say *correct something to something*? For example:

> In your last sentence I **corrected** the word "left" **to** "laughed" because it makes more sense.

If it's not natural, what would you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a native speaker that usage of "correct" sounds both correct and natural. When using it like that, some people may be more apt to say "changed" instead of "correct." That being said, if the context does not make it clear that a correction is being made, then using "correct" actually sounds better and can be used like in the example.